# Change text on view inside delegate method

Tags: swift

I want to change some text on a label. This works as expected at the viewDidLoad method. But this doesn't work inside an delegate method.

The code:

```
class testView: UIViewController, RTCPeerConnectionDelegate, RTCDataChannelDelegate, RTCEAGLVideoViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!




    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    public func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCIceConnectionState){

       if(newState == RTCIceConnectionState.connected){
             DispatchQueue.main.async {                    
                self.statusLabel.text = "Connected";
             }
       }  
    }

}
```

I have tried to run the "label update" code on the main tread. This did not work unfortunately. Why isn't this working?

Update:

I have tried this with a delegate, but with no luck:

```
class testView: UIViewController, RTCPeerConnectionDelegate, RTCDataChannelDelegate, RTCEAGLVideoViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var statusLabel: UILabel!
    var delegate : testView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        delegate = self
    }

    public func peerConnection(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection, didChange newState: RTCIceConnectionState){

       if(newState == RTCIceConnectionState.connected){
             DispatchQueue.main.async {                    
                self.delegate.statusLabel.text = "Connected";
             }
       }  
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you forget to set `self` as the delegate?

Comment: Have you checked if the `self.statusLabel.text = "Connected"` is actually called? The `newState` may be not `.connected`? `peerConnection` may be not called? Sprinkle `print` everywhere to trace.

Comment: @kennytm Yes the method is called, and the if statement is executed.

Comment: Did you make sure the outlet is actually connected to the storyboard?

Comment: @ThomasKrajacic Yes, because it works if I do the "statusLabel.text" at the view did load

Comment: Could it be that the view isn't loaded when the delegate is called? (Sorry, just guessing here atm)

Comment: @ThomasKrajacic I am using the notificationCenter to pass the message to another method. This works. Thank you for your help:)